# my application not referencing latest dll from gac

Tags: 2007, gac

I updated latest dll to my gac but still getting error in my application that this method doesn't exists, for some reason I have to get it from Gac and dunno why its not updating it even I did IIS reset so many times

Comment: Pleas add more information your question. What kind of application would be a good start.

Comment: Indeed, please let us also know if this is some sort of user control, page, etc. I would also presume that you'd want to check the reference in your code to make sure you are utilizing the latest version.

Comment: its timer job in sharepoint using a feature

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please edit  your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

In your project are you referencing to the right dll aswell as it will be calling that dll in GAC? can you check for duplicates in GAC of the same DLL but different version?